# Keeping track of an entry's index in Tkinter menus

Tags: python, tkinter, menuitem

I don't have a lot of GUI programming experience and very little in Tkinter, so bear with me. It seems to me that the Tkinter menu interface is seriously wrong. I'm referring in particular to the way menu entries are addressed.

Menu entries are not widgets. `add_command` - or, for that matter, any `add` - does not return an object which we can use to address the entry. In order to

- reconfigure
- delete
- insert relative to

an entry, an index must be provided. The index is, usually, just an index in the current list of entries in the menu. That means, all entries that exist (after additions and deletions) at the present time in the index.

It seems logical to organize the code in a GUI around groups of functions that are related from a user's point of view. Say, Undo and Redo should be together in the Edit menu. But the Edit menu may also contain other groups of functions - Cut, Copy, Paste, or perhaps Find. It makes sense to put the code that handles Undo and Redo in one module, the code for Cut, Copy and Paste in another, the code for Find in yet another. These modules are unrelated to each other, except for the fact that they all exist in the Edit menu. However, just because of that fact, it seems that in Tkinter menus they need to know if a module "above" inserts or deletes an entry in its own "area", because that affects the indices of their own entries. Isn't that quite fragile? Or am I missing something?

Comment: If you have to you can wrap the functionality you need.

Comment: yes, I can do that. It's just that I don't understand why methods like add do not return some sort of object or id that is attached to the item added regardless of how many items happen to exist above it

Comment: It's probably because the underlying Tk doesn't do it that way.

Comment: Are you aware that you can use the item label as an index? Does that knowledge help answer your question?

Comment: Yes, definitely. I wasn't aware of that.